# Are there hosts for hidden services?

Tags: onion-services, web-hosting

I am exploring putting up a simple page as a hidden service advertising business formation and nominee services. Does anyone offer hosted pages?

I think I don't really need an entire site, just a way of communicating our services as a bridge between the anonymous-world and the public-world.

Background: We are a law firm with a subsidiary that caters to privacy-minded individuals and businesses. That means that we operate in full daylight but want customers to know that we respect their privacy concerns and have strategies to support them.

Answer (score 2):

A hidden service is most useful when you wish to provide a service while trying to remain anonymous.  They are also useful for users testing .onion reachability from their Tor Browser.  Finally, they can be used to encourage Tor use, while incidentally limiting the visitors to the service to those capable of running Tor or using a .onion gateway site.

Your described needs for privacy-minded client services don't require anonymity. As well, you probably don't want to restrict the number of visitors artificially.

Instead, in your case it may be better to make sure your main site is reachable via Tor exit nodes while encouraging visitors to use the Tor Browser Bundle or Tails for reaching it.

Comment: The way you say it makes a lot of sense. Basically, that's right, I'm trying to signal to prospective clients that we understand where they are coming from, not really providing an hidden service. At the same time, it seems like it would be cool to have a .onion foothold. There are probably other ways to gently market to the community.

Answer (score 0):

If your current hosting provider offers a shell, then you can install tor there using something like Homebrew (which now includes Linuxbrew).  Assuming your website has its own IP (it's not name-based shared hosting), you can set up a hidden service that points at your IP/port.  Then your whole website will be available through tor.